# How to get a python dict from kivy dictProperty?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, properties, kivy

I've made some classic Python3 functions, in a file, using dictionaries as arguments. I'd like to use this file as a library, and use the functions in a kivy widget.
So here's what my code does :

```
#all kivy imports
import myLib

class MyGame(Widget):
    myDict = DictProperty({1:0, 2:0, 3:0})

    def addStuff(self, id):
        self.myDict[id]+= 1

    def myNotWorkingFunction(self):
        number = myLib.getNumberFromDict(self.myDict)
        self.text = "The result is "+str(number)
```

It doesn't work like that. If I don't use `myLib.getNumberFromDict`, and set `number = 3`, it's fine.
`myLib.getNumberFromDict` works well with python `dict`, as I used it before trying to make the kivy app.

I have this in the kivy log :

```
stderr: Exception KeyError: ('', ) in 'kivy.properties.observable_dict_dispatch' ignored
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work!
It was the obvious way: the cast!

```
number = myLib.getNumberFromDict(dict(self.myDict))
```

Works well, I get the expected result in number.